# How do I solve this Venn Diagram problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have a problem that reads as follows.

A random sample of 330 people showed that 120 people like Italian food, 210 people like Mexican food, and 220 people like American food. If 60 like both Italian and Mexican, 75 like both Italian and American, and 100 like both Mexican and American, how many people like all three?

From which I made a diagram that looks like the one below. How do I find **M ∩ A ∩ I**? The best I can reason using the limits of **M ∩ I** and **I** is that the answer must be between 15 and 60 inclusively.

[image: Model of Problem]

Comment: Use $n(A ∪ B ∪ C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) – n(A ∩ B) – n(B ∩ C) – n(A ∩ C) + n(A ∩ B ∩ C)$

Comment: Or you can mark it with x, calculate how many people are in other areas (e.g. 60-x like Italian and Mexican but not American). Then from numbers on the diagram find out how many people there are in total, expressed with x. That has to match 330 (see the beginning of the question).

Comment: The problem probably assumes that every person in this sample likes at least one of these foods.

Comment: Shraddheya's solution was the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Venn diagram below:

[image]

$$\begin{cases}
a+b+c+d+x+y+z+t=330 \\ 
a+x+y+z=120 \\ 
b+x+y+t=210 \\
c+x+t+z=220 \\
x+y=60\\ 
x+z=75 \\
x+t=100
\end{cases}
$$

Assuming $d=0$ (no one dislikes all three foods): $x=(1)– \left[(2)+(3)+(4)\right]+\left[(5)+(6)+(7)\right]=15.$